# Account for Performing Dirctory Lookups in AD

Tags: active-directory, user-accounts

I have a question about accounts that can be used to perform directory lookups. I need to have an account that can perform lookups for an application, however it needs to have the minimum permissions needed to do this. Does anyone know whether it is possible to have an account that can perform directory lookups that is not an administrator? I thought that it was, but need to know which group it needs to be assigned so that it has the least privileges whilst still being able to perform lookups.

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A user does not need to be an administrator to look up data in the directory.

It all depends on what you want the account to access.  Assuming you haven't changed any ACLs in your directory, then by default a user who is only in 'Domain Users', will be able to retrieve all the basic details about users/groups/objects in your domain.  They won't be everything, some fields are protected and require admin access (e.g. passwords).

It would be a bad idea, but you could even enable [anonymous access](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320528) and then you would not need any accounts at all.

If you have different requirements you can set ACLs on your OUs and grant the privileges you want.

Comment: Agreed, only needs to be domain user. Agree, DO NOT use anonymous access!

Comment: Great, thanks I'll try this with a basic user then and it should work - I hvaen't changed any of the ACL's in the directory.

Comment: It's actually sufficient if the user is part of Domain Guests.